# Custom Mamba installation directory

Tags: conda, mamba, mambaforge

I want to install Mamba on a HPC, and when you go through the normal installation procedure, it will be installed in the $HOME directory.

[Installation](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/tree/main):

```
$ curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
$ bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
```

After installation:

```
(base) [user@login-p-1 ~]$ which mamba
~/mambaforge/bin/mamba
(base) [user@login-p-1 ~]$
```

Is there a way to set the installation directory manually? On our HPC system, the $HOME directory is limited to 50 GB, which is not sufficient when installing multiple Mamba environments.

Comment: There's some related guidance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69213384/570918). Basically, I'd still recommend keeping **base** in the user home, but change the package cache and environments directory (`pkgs_dirs`, `envs_dirs`) to point to a volume with more storage. You should not be using **base** environment for work, so it should stay small.